# How can I use VBScript to effectively refresh the external data of several Excel spreadsheets?

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have a macro in one XLSM workbook's module that refreshes all the external data, then saves and closes that workbook.

```
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.Quit
```

I use a VBScript file to run that macro as part of a scheduled task

```
objExcel.Workbooks.Open(fname)
objExcel.Visible = True
On error resume next
objExcel.Run "RefreshAllData"
```

Question: How can I reuse the existing macro in the existing workbook to refresh all the data of multiple other workbooks? (ie. I'm looking for the necessary modifications to the VBScript file, I want to minimise changes to the macro itself. The filenames will be contained in the VBScript file) TIA.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd recommend against re-using a trivial macro like that. Instead incorporate the refresh functionality in the VBScript:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set xl  = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\some\folder").Files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f.Name)) = "xlsx" Then
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(f.Path)
    wb.RefreshAll
    wb.Save
    wb.Close
  End If
Next

xl.Quit
```

Comment: I'll follow your advice. Great concise answer. Thanks Ansgar.

Comment: This is gold! I just have a single question in regards to this. When I run it, I get a pop up box saying: "This will cancel a pending data refresh. Continue? [OK] [Cancel]"
I assume its because the data refresh hasnt had enough time to run, is there a way to make it wait for the refresh to finish before saving and closing? @Ansgar Wiechers

Comment: @KhalidN You seem to have an [asynchronous query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835909.aspx) somewhere. Either change that to a synchronous one, or add a delay before saving/closing the workbook (`WScript.Sleep`).

Comment: How do I add a WScript.Sleep while it is in the "For Each f" code? 
I am only using the code that you have written, haven't added a asynchronous query anywhere?

Comment: I placed WScript.Sleep 30000 between wb.RefreshAll and wb.Save, and it did the trick. thanks for the help

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, I am using this code in order to run a Task Scheduler on a server. I have no problem using it when "Run only when user is logged in" but it does not run when I use "Run whether user is logged on or not". Well it says it runs, but nothing happens. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: @KhalidN That's a different question, so please post it as a new question.

Comment: I have created a new post regarding my question, hope you will have an oppertunity to look it over [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32713149/automate-the-process-of-updating-sql-data-in-excel-through-vbscript-on-server) @AnsgarWiechers

Comment: this works but it is saying "a file named XYZ already exists in this location. Do you want to replace it?" how do i avoid this? 
BAckground: using vbscript to refresh all in excel file stored in sharepoint. dont want that message as i want to put this on task scheduler to run on its own. I have .DisplayAlerts = False already but somehow that does not work

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can do something like this.

1. Find all the excel file in the given folder
2. Select Each Excel file and activate
3. call refreshdata function

## code snippet to support this

```
Sub RefreshAllExcelInFolder()
    Dim fso
    Dim ObjFolder
    Dim ObjFiles
    Dim ObjFile
    Dim objExcel

    'Creating File System Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Getting the Folder Object
    Set ObjFolder = fso.GetFolder("<<C:folder path>>")

    'Getting the list of Files
    Set ObjFiles = ObjFolder.Files
        'On Error Resume Next
        For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
            If LCase(Right(ObjFile.Name, 5)) = ".xlsx" Or LCase(Right(ObjFile.Name, 4)) = ".xls" Then
                Workbooks.Open(ObjFile).Activate
                RefreshAllData
            End If
        Next
End Sub

Sub RefreshAllData()
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    MsgBox ("Going back In")
End Sub
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Well done. I like an answer that teaches me more than just the answer itself, without actually going overboard with a whole whitepaper. Thanks Dharmesh.

Comment: glad to be help and to see that the purpose of answer is served ,to teach..For concise code, i would recommend Ansgar's post

Comment: I think you forgot to create the Excel object though!

Comment: did i needed to ? cos i am handling it via active excel object only ! why to create new excelobject when there is no need to

Answer (score 1):

If you don't change the macro at all you will have to keep reloading excel, then open the macro workbook followed by the target workbook and then run the macro. If you can remove:

```
Application.quit
```

then you can at least keep excel open and just keep opening target workbooks before running the macro each time. Seems to me it'd be simpler to put the macro code into the vbs file though