# Automate the process of updating SQL data in Excel through VBScript on server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

I have access to an external server, and I have linked a Excel sheet with the SQL server so I can retrieve the data. But I want an internal server to automatically retrieve the data at a specific time each week. The internal server is always on, but I will not be logged in while the retrieval should happen.

The way I have set up the automatical retrieval is by using Task Scheduler to run a batch file that runs the vbscript. When I test the task with the "Run only when user is logged in" but it does not run when I use "Run whether user is logged on or not". Well it says it runs, but nothing happens.

Any ideas on how to fix this so it can run while no user is logged in?

The VBScript is run through a batch file, but I don't know how necessary this is, the code is as follows:

```
cscript.exe "C:\Users\XX.YY\Desktop\ZZZ\Test\Test.vbs"
```

The code for the VBScript is as follows:

```
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set xl  = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 xl.Visible = True

 For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\XX.YY\Desktop\ZZZ\Test").Files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f.Name)) = "xlsx" Then
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(f.Path)
    wb.RefreshAll
    WScript.sleep 30000
    wb.Save
    wb.Close
  End If
Next

xl.Quit
```

Comment: what does the logs tells you for unattended runs? does any messagebox happens during attended run?

Comment: No messagebox pops up, but the following happens in the "history" tab:
[EventID 107 - Task Triggered on scheduler],          [319 - Task engine received message to start task],            [100 - Task started],          [200 - Action started],         [129 - Created Task Process],          [201 - Action Completed],          [102 - Task Completed]

Comment: @Paolo, forgot to tag you on the answer