# VBS: Wait until Excel RefreshAll is complete

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have an Excel file with a database connection. I need to run VBS (not VBA!) which opens that Excel file, does "RefreshAll", waits until refresh is complete, then saves the Excel file.

Here's a VBS script that I got:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.DisplayAlerts = False
xl.Visible = True

Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(full_path)
wb.RefreshAll
wb.Save
wb.Close
```

The problem is that VBS doesn't wait for wb.RefreshAll to complete.

In VBA the solution would be something like (I honestly googled across Stackoverflow and here's a brief overview):

- wb.RefreshAll BackgroundQuery:=False
- Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
- DoEvents

But you can do that only in VBA context, not VBS.
How can I do that in VBS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932104/how-can-i-use-vbscript-to-effectively-refresh-the-external-data-of-several-excel#comment53227210_16936245

Comment: @BigBen The solution is to make VBS sleep? But that's a duct tape=( I thought there's a way to set backgroundquery attribute to False. But probably I am right that you can't do that in VBS context.